# Can OpenCV comparisons be done in floating point? Or can this be made more efficient some other way?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

Bad question title, I know, sorry.

I have this little piece of code which is extremely inefficient and slow and gets called a lot:

```
    // frequencies is a 256 element cv::Mat array, already with values
    // values in frequencies may exceed 255
    // grey is a cv::Mat, type CV_8U
    cv::Mat inc, inc32;

    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
        inc = (grey > i);   
        inc.convertTo(inc32, CV_32F);
        frequencies[i] = inc32/255 + frequencies[i];
    }
```

inc becomes a type CV_8U, because that is what compare (or the '>') returns, but I need a floating point 1.0 or 0.0. So I have to convert it to inc32, then divide by 255. This seems really inefficient and slow, making an extra cv::Mat for no real reason.

I've tried doing the addition element-wise instead, but that was a disaster (about 3 times as slow).

So, is there a more efficient way I can do this, such as somehow making compare store a 1.0 in a float type Mat? I'm thinking of re-implementing the OpenCV compare to do what I need, or maybe a strategy that requires the Mat to be contiguous, but I'm new(ish) to OpenCV and don't want to reinvent wheels or write fragile code just yet.

For those who might be interested, I'm writing a time based histogram per pixel so that I can retrieve any quantile I like (so, say, a frame of the median pixels by time, or the first quartile . . .) There may already be a better way to do this that I've overlooked. The code works, it is just a lot slower than I'd hoped.

Thanks for any pointers in advance! (The advice kind of pointers, not the other kind, though they are welcome too.)

Comment: Why your converting `inc` to `CV_32F` inside the for loop? You can move it outside the loop!

Comment: @elvis.dukaj: Because it depends on the loop variable `ì`.

Comment: Please try this an let me know: `for (int i=0; i<256; i++) { add(frequencies[i], 1.0, frequencies[i],   grey > i);}`. I'll post as an answer if it's fast enough for you... I cannot test the performance now...

Comment: Thanks for the comment Miki, I really thought it would do the job, but unfortunately, quite the opposite! With some test data, 200 iterations, my original takes ~6195 ms in this function, whereas with the changes you suggest, ~9125ms! My test environment isn't perfect, but the results are consistent over multiple runs, and with the difference, I would say that my inefficient original is significantly faster.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious fix is to do the math on CV_8U, before the conversion. I wouldn't use a division either, but just a `& 1` mask.

However, you have to understand that OpenCV convenience comes at a price. You say " an extra cv::Mat" but I count more: inc = (grey>i), inc32 and also inc32/255.

Comment: The & 1 I can definitely do, which may add some speeed, true. And yes, 3 mats used, which is an issue. I can't convert after (if I understand you correctly) because each value in frequencies can (and usually does) exceed 255.

Comment: I tried the '&' operator, but it doesn't appear to be overloaded for cv::Mat objects. I could try the forEach (and thinking of trying that as an overall approach somehow) but I doubt I'm going to see a significant speedup, if any, from that approach.